# Delete characters from string between 2 characters

Tags: c#, string, character

Input string (3) examples:

```
+31 +31 31 888 00 98
+236+2323902341122
+41   +41416185825
```

Output wanted:

```
+31 31 888 00 98
+2323902341122
+41416185825
```

How I'd delete the characters between the first + and second +. Is there also a way to do it without Regex? Anyway Regex would be fine too.

I tried this:

```
int indexUP = myString.IndexOf('[');
int indexClose = myString.IndexOf(']', indexUP + 1);


string results = myString.Substring(0, indexUP ) + myString.Substring(indexClose + 1);
```

But this works with two different characters only. My delimiter is a '+'.

Comment: Doesn't your code work if you change `']'` to `'+'` (and remove the `+ 1` from your second `SubString`)?

Comment: well it does work then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @petelids who pointed out, that my initial try-out code worked - with just a bit of change:

```
int indexUP = myString.IndexOf('+');
int indexClose = myString.IndexOf('+', indexUP + 1);
string results = myString.Substring(0, indexUP ) + myString.Substring(indexClose).Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem. You need to find the index of the + sign after the first its occurrence.

```
string str = "+31 +31 31 888 00 98";
int index = str.IndexOf('+', str.IndexOf('+')+1);
if(index>0)
    str = str.Substring(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more. Solution generic to any possible pre number of '+' symbols.

```
 string myString = "+236+2323902341122";
 List<char> list= myString.ToList();
 int index = list.FindLastIndex(x=> x=='+');
 string resultString = myString.Substring(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

With regex:

```
var x = new Regex(@"([\+]{1}.*)([\+]{1}.*)").Match(s).Groups[2];
```

where `s` - input string.

Answer (score 1):

Using Replace method on a Regex object:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(  
  @"\+[\d\s]*\+",  
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline  
);  
string example =  
  @"+31 +31 31 888 00 98  
  +236+2323902341122  
  +41   +41416185825";

return myRegex.Replace(example, "+");
```

This will replace all pluses signs containing numbers and white-spaces by a single plus sign and should be what you are looking for.

This output the following:

> +31 31 888 00 98
>   +2323902341122
>   +41416185825